# Ability to generate ports as per requirement

Tags: javascript, gojs

I require a method by which I can add ports to a Node as per the requirement of each node.So if a node requires 3 ports it must generate just 3 not more or less. The node template creates the same no of ports for each node which is where my problem begins.

I've tried creating a function for creating a port and then calling that function in a loop to generate i no of ports. The function works to generate just one port but if the loop executes the second time it doesnt work. I have also tried using the addPort function from the Dynamic Ports example and that too doesn't seem to give me the required result.

```
function portGen(i){
                    ports=myDiag.model.nodeDataArray[0].ports;
                    arr=new Array();
                    return $(go.Panel, "Horizontal",
                                { column: 0, row: i+2 },
                                $(go.Shape,  // the "A" port
                                { width: 2, height: 2, portId: String(i+1), toSpot: go.Spot.Left, toLinkable:true, fromLinkable:true, toMaxLinks: 1 }),
                                $(go.TextBlock, String(i+1)) ) // "A" port label
                                }

Essentially I would lke to call the portGen function multiple times based on the no of ports to be created.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify the template after it has been used.  Instead, have your node data include an Array of descriptions of the ports that you want that node to have, and bind Panel.itemArray to that property.

Please read https://gojs.net/latest/intro/itemArrays.html and look at samples such as https://gojs.net/latest/samples/records.html or https://gojs.net/latest/samples/dynamicPorts.html.